# How to get specific item having same class name and attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I get the specific item with same Class name and attributes?

I need to get these 3 items

> April 14, 2013
>
> 580
>
> Fort Pierce, FL

```
<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Joined:</dt>
<dd>Apr 14, 2013</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Messages:</dt>
<dd><a href="search/member?user_id=13302" class="concealed" 
rel="nofollow">580</a></dd>
</dl>

<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Location:</dt>
<dd>
<a href="misc/location-info?location=Fort+Pierce%2C+FL" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow noreferrer" itemprop="address" class="concealed">Fort 
Pierce, FL</a>
```

Comment: so you want the text content of all `dd` tags within all `dl` tags with `class="pairsJustified"`?

Comment: whats the url so I can see what the best xpath is in case there are other instances of that tag/classname combo?

Comment: Hi @Verbal_Kint here's the URL https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a good starting point:

```
In [18]: for a in response.css('.extraUserInfo'):
    ...:     print(a.css('*::text').extract())
    ...:     print('\n\n\n')
    ...:     
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']  # <--this (and other outputs like this) is because there is an extra `extraUserInfo` class block above the desired info block if the user has a user group picture/avatar below their username




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Mar 24, 2013', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '6,747', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Mar 24, 2013', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '6,747', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Apr 14, 2013', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '580', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Location:', '\n', '\n', 'Fort Pierce, FL', '\n', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Oct 20, 2012', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '2,476', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Location:', '\n', '\n', 'Philadelphia, PA', '\n', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Dec 11, 2012', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '2,938', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Location:', '\n', '\n', 'Colorado', '\n', '\n', '\n']




['\n', '\n', 'Joined:', '\n', 'Sep 30, 2016', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Messages:', '\n', '833', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Location:', '\n', '\n', 'Indiana', '\n', '\n', '\n']


...
```

There are many ways to approach this. A little fiddling around will get the data formatted to your liking. The approach above is only a good starting point because there are many lines with only newline character lists as outputs, thats because (it seems) that user info blocks where the user has a user-group image (like tesla of arizona) then the `extraUserInfo` class is also used to group that block of html. There will be better ways to group this...

Basically response.css('.extraUserInfo') will aggregate all blocks with class `extraUserInfo` which seems to be the blocks holding the user info you're looking for.
From there extract all underlying text with the `::text` pseudo selector and parse the arrays.

There is definitely a better way to approach this if you carefully look at the html structure so you are extracting it in a way that leaves you less processing work afterwards but this should get you on the right track. CSS selectors or xpath documentation should be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Using they lie under the `<dd>` tag, using `.find_all()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test = '''<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Joined:</dt>
<dd>Apr 14, 2013</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Messages:</dt>
<dd><a href="search/member?user_id=13302" class="concealed" 
rel="nofollow">580</a></dd>
</dl>

<dl class="pairsJustified">
<dt>Location:</dt>
<dd>
<a href="misc/location-info?location=Fort+Pierce%2C+FL" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow noreferrer" itemprop="address" class="concealed">Fort Pierce, FL</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("dd")
for d in data:
    print(d.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Apr 14, 2013
580
Fort Pierce, FL
```

Comment: he's using scrapy

Comment: Hi @dirtyBit I am using Scrapy , still thank you for helping me :)